# how to use a queryselector on object HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying that when the text field has focus, the `div` is selected with the class:`autocomplete`, this is an example to understand my idea, in my real problem it is more complex. I simply need that once the element that has the focus is identified, select the nearest `div` with `.autocomplete` class on the same level, I want to get it this way. I know that in css I should use something like:

```
input ~ div.autocomplete
($event.target is input in my case)
```

but I don't know how to do it in this case. Thank you.

```js
function fn_selectAutocompleteClass($event) {
  console.log(($event.target));
}
```

```css
.selectAutocomplete {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" onfocus="fn_selectAutocompleteClass(event)">
<i class="icon"></i>
<div class="autocomplete">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum itaque placeat, ad vel reprehenderit illo, harum nemo laudantium, dolorem unde aut distinctio! Consectetur vitae deleniti veritatis autem numquam officia eaque.</div>
```

Comment: Why link to a jsfiddle when you can just use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can access the `.autocomplete` using the `querySelectorAll` on the target elements parent like below snippet. Get the 0th index as that will be the first element matching the selector query.

```js
function fn_selectAutocompleteClass($event) {
  console.log($event.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete')[0]);

}
```

```css
.selectAutocomplete {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" onfocus="fn_selectAutocompleteClass(event)">
<i class="icon"></i>
<div class="autocomplete">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum itaque placeat, ad vel reprehenderit illo, harum nemo laudantium, dolorem unde aut distinctio! Consectetur vitae deleniti veritatis autem numquam officia eaque.</div>
```

Hope this helps :)